# Partial derivative of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying Complex Functions for the first time in my life. I read the Cauchy-Riemann equations and I found something incredible to me: a partial derivative written as

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial iy}$$

**with the imaginary unit at the denominator.**
What's the geometrical meaning of this?